# Multiple connections to the same serial port

Tags: networking, serial-port, tcp-ip

I'm trying to connect to clients to the same serial port.
The serial port is shared over the network with TCP on port 1234.
I tried with `socat tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork tcp:remote-ip:1234` but this works well with just one client, when a second one connects it just forks a new connection to the remote server that close the previous one.

What I need is socat to not open a new connection but just send the same data to every client connected and when receiving data from one client send it to the remote server.

It should be really easy to do but I found no solution that works.

Comment: Serial communication doesn't work like that, the port cannot be shared. You must have a process that listens to the serial port, and distributes the data to the clients.